# How do I clear the GNU screen command screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

Running "screen" for example with:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

How do I clear the screen once in a while?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113427/how-to-clear-the-scrollback-in-the-screen-command)

1. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
2. `clear`
3. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> and entering the command `scrollback 0`.

Comment: According to the [GNU Screen User’s Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Clear), the standard way to create a new window is to type `C-a c` (lowercase c). `C-a C` (uppercase C) Clears the screen and saves its contents to the scrollback buffer. It is not the same or I misread?

Comment: Thanks @Gounou yes I'll edit the answer.